# How can I change the JDK version into JDK 10 in NetBeans?

Tags: java, installation

I want to change my JDK version to JDK 10, I installed it and all, but I couldn't change it from NetBeans
I tried to change the path from netbeans.conf, but it seems like the path is invalid, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Not dup. NetBeans 8.2 and older does not support JDK 9+. You need NetBeans 9 or above, which is still in development at April 2018. You can download the beta version from [Apache NetBeans site](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html). Just tested RC3 (released Feb 2018), runs on JDK 10.0.1, can compile and run and debug.